# Mongoose virtual is giving undefined response for the field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a use case where I need to modify a field before I save and modify back when I get it. I am using mongoose virtual to do it. Here is my code to do it.

```
const newSchema = new Schema({ ip: String });
newSchema.virtual('ipAddress')
  .get(function(){ return ip.fromLong(this.ip) })
  .set(function(v) { this.ip = ip.toLong(v) });
```

When i call `model.create({ ipAddress: '255.255.255.255' })`, ip is undefined. I tried assigning a hardcoded value, to `this.ip` in the setter, even then it is undefined. Am i missing anything in the flow?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create with input data what is not like the model schema (virtual field are not stored in MongoDB).
Following official document:

```
var IPModel = mongoose.model('IPTableName', newSchema);
var obj = new IPModel({
    ip: ''
});
obj.ipAddress = '255.255.255.255'; // call setter
obj.save();
```